# Are properties of bilinear forms independent of basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form, change-of-basis

Let $H:V\times V\to \mathbb{R}$ be a bilinear form. Let $\beta=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and $\gamma=\{w_1,\dots,w_n\}$ be two ordered bases for $V$, and let $Q$ be the change of basis matrix. Let there matrix representations be $\psi_\beta(H)$ and $\psi_\gamma(H)$ respectively.

Then a theorem says that $$\psi_\gamma(H)=Q^T\psi_\beta(H) Q.$$

What's confusing me is that there is no reason $Q^T=Q^{-1}$. Hence, the bilinear form is not independent of basis; in particular $$\det(\psi_\gamma(H))=\det(\psi_\beta(H))\det(Q)^2.$$ Shouldn't properties of bilinear forms be indepdent of coordinates, just like for linear transformations?

Comment: I don't think the question here is quite well-defined, inasmuch as "properties" is not. Some properties of matrix representations of bilinear forms are independent of the choice of basis (for example, the sign of the determinant), others are not (the determinant itself). The same is true for properties of matrix representations of linear transformations (for example, the value of the top-left entry is not independent in this way).

Comment: Do you understand why the transpose is used instead of the inverse for change-of-basis of bilinear forms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bilinear form in the first place is a function $H\colon\>V\times V\to{\mathbb R}$ defined on pairs $(x,y)$ of points $x$, $y\in V$, and has nothing to to with bases. The choice of a basis $\beta$ in $V$ has the effect that the information inherent in $H$ can be encoded in a matrix $\psi_\beta(H)$. If the basis $\beta$ is replaced by some other basis $\gamma$ then a new matrix $\psi_\gamma(H)$ will result. Fortunately it turns out that the two matrices $\psi_\beta(H)$ and $\psi_\gamma(H)$ are related by the simple formula you quote.

You have to accept that this formula does not look the way you had hoped for, in particular that ${\rm det}\bigl(\psi_\beta(H)\bigr)$ is not an invariant of $H$. But other things that can be read off from the matrix $\psi_\beta(H)$ are, e.g., the rank of $\psi_\beta(H)$, and an eventual positive definiteness of the quadratic form$q(x):=H(x,x)$.